# php while loop that lists unique entries and counts total number of each one

Tags: php, mysql

**Question: How can I create a while loop that lists unique names and a count of how many times that name is listed in database?**

*I will never know what names will be listed in database at any given time so I cannot hard code this.*

### Database:

```
|   id   |   name    |    age    |
|   1    |   Bob     |    35     |
|   2    |   Jake    |    30     |
|   3    |   Bob     |    25     |
|   4    |   Bob     |    45     |
|   5    |   Jake    |    78     |
|   6    |   Heather |    23     |
```

### code to sort by name

```
$query = $con->query("SELECT id,name,age FROM table order by name ASC")
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
while ($result = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
// while loop
}
}
```

### Ideal Results

```
Bob (3)
Heather (1)
Jake (2)
```

I don't know if this is php code in while loop or if this is a specific query I can run to achieve this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in your SQL query...

```
$query = $con->query("SELECT name, count(id) as total
                         FROM table 
                         group by name 
                         order by name ASC")
```

Using count(id) will count the number of id's within the group by name.

**Update:**
The other answer gives you a way of doing it inside a for loop.  But another version is if you do something like...

```
$query = $con->query("SELECT id,name,age FROM table order by name ASC")
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    $data = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $names = array_column($data, 'name');
    $count = array_count_values($names);
    print_r($count);
}
```

This just fetches all of the data from the SQL statement, then extract the name column and count the unique values from this array.

Comment: is there an easy way to do this via php inside the while loop?  Trying to modify something where I think I'd have more control if I could do it inside the while loop.  The only thing I could think of is to create an array and then count and loop through array

Comment: Your PHP solution is even better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

While I would usually do it in SQL with `GROUP_BY` and `COUNT()` - If you ever need to do it in PHP you can use one of the follwing ways.

Assuming you have data in this form:

```
$data = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Bob',     'age' => 35],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Jake',    'age' => 30],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Bob',     'age' => 25],
    ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Bob',     'age' => 45],
    ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Jake',    'age' => 78],
    ['id' => 6, 'name' => 'Heather', 'age' => 23],
];
```

One method would be:

```
$counts = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if (isset($counts[$row['name']])) {
        $counts[$row['name']] += 1;
    } else {
        $counts[$row['name']] = 1;
    }
}
```

And here is another one, which is (IMHO) more elegant, but slower:

```
$groups = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $groups[$row['name']][] = $row;
}
$counts = array_map('count', $groups);
```

Both methods would create an array like this:

```
[
  'Bob' => 3,
  'Jake' => 2,
  'Heather' => 1,
];
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/PTCC84943

The foreach loop can also be replced with `while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc())`